# What's an effective text editor for html code violation warnings?

Tags: text-editor, html

I'll be using the text editor to clean up the bloat from a Word doc saved as "web page filter" (ie. html). Then I am going to convert the .html into a .epub. Eventually it will be on Amazon et al. as an ebook (novel).

I am using Xubnutu 13.10, 32 bit.

What I have used that worked very well for me in the past (and I know this is an epub editor) was Sigil. When I'm working there and I make an error in an html tag right away a big red warning pops up in the companion "view" screen and then I stop and set right the error.

The key feature I'm looking for is this code violation notification. Other features would be snytax highlighting and search and replace. And it would be nice if it was available for free.

Comment: We have a sister site that does accept requests for recommendations, but your question needs to meet [certain guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). In particular, all questions must both define a goal or task to accomplish, and list some objective requirements. Please read the guidelines and improve your question accordingly, then you can repost your question on the Software Recommendations site.

Comment: Many duplicates of what's a good text editor exist in Ask Ubuntu. There's nothing special about Xubuntu. What applies to others applies to Xubuntu as far as text editors go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) should do the job, accompanied by the [SublimeLinter plugin](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2).

[Bluefish](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bluefish/) is a (financially) free option, accompanied by [weblint](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/weblint-perl/) (which only supports HTML4 and not HTML5).

Comment: Are there any text editors that fit the bill free?

Comment: You're welcome! If you think this answer was useful, please [upvote it](http://askubuntu.com/help/why-vote)! If this answer satisfies your question and was what you were looking for, then please mark it as the accepted answer!

Comment: Thx, Dot. Happy to vote it up and accept it. However, I'm still searching for that text editor with the features I mentioned. I did have Bluefish for a while but it, alone, did not fit the bill. I did not know what you meant by using Bluefish "accompanied" by weblint. As I am very new, perhaps you could explain--step-by-step always helps--how I could combine Bluefish and weblint to give me the code notification features I'm looking for. Thanks.